# Test if the difference is statistically significant in A/B test

Tags: hypothesis-testing

Let's say we did an A/B testing, and the click rate for 1 group was 0.4 and for the other group, it was 0.3.

How can we go about testing whether this difference is statistically significant?
I'm thinking getting a p-value from t-test, but what would the null and alternative hypothesis be?

Comment: First, you need the sizes of the groups. Typically in a simple situation one would test whether the *difference* between the groups was significantly different from zero. This site has further information: http://stattrek.com/hypothesis-test/difference-in-proportions.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can do a test for difference of binomial proportions. You will need to know how many people were presented with A and with B.

For example, if there were 50 shown each, Stata gives the following result:

```
. prtesti 50 .4 50 .3

Two-sample test of proportions                     x: Number of obs =       50
                                                   y: Number of obs =       50
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Variable |       Mean   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
           x |         .4    .069282                      .2642097    .5357903
           y |         .3   .0648074                      .1729798    .4270202
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
        diff |         .1   .0948683                     -.0859385    .2859385
             |  under Ho:   .0953939     1.05   0.295
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        diff = prop(x) - prop(y)                                  z =   1.0483
    Ho: diff = 0

    Ha: diff < 0                 Ha: diff != 0                 Ha: diff > 0
 Pr(Z < z) = 0.8527         Pr(|Z| < |z|) = 0.2945          Pr(Z > z) = 0.1473
```

Imagining that you wanted a one-tailed hypothesis test to see if the "new group" was better than the old group, you would look at `Ha: diff > 0` which gives a p-value of 0.15, i.e., not statistically significant (at standard significance level of 0.05).

If you instead showed to 500 each the p-value is 0.0005, so very much statistically significant.

See the [Stata documentation for prtest](http://www.stata.com/manuals13/rprtest.pdf) to understand the methods used by the command.